# Saving Path and file info to mysql while using curl

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Am using Shared server.

I can save external images using curl. But am unable to save the path and file info to mysql.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
 <tr><td><b>URL: </b> </td><td><input type="**text**" name="url" id="url" size=40></td>  </tr>
 <tr><th colspan=2><p><input name="upload" type="submit" class="box" id="upload" value="Upload"></p></th></tr>
 </table>
 </form>

 <?php

 set_time_limit(0);
 ini_set('display_errors',true);//Just in case we get some errors, let us know....

 if (isset($_POST['upload']))
 {

  $url = $_POST['url'];
  $dir = "./files/";

  $fileName = $_FILES['url']['name'];
  $fileSize = $_FILES['url']['size'];
  $fileType = $_FILES['url']['type'];
  $filePath = $dir . $fileName;

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  $fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
  $ch = curl_init($remote_file);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
  curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  include ('db.php');
  if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
  $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
  $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
  }
  $query = "INSERT INTO upload2 (name, size, type, path ) ". "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$filePath')";
 mysql_query($query);
 mysql_close($conn);
 }
```

It is not working when I change input type to text from file.

I need to get file info and save to mysql server

Comment: I presume you have removed a whole bunch of cURL code here? Just so I'm clear, what you want to is upload a file from the user's computer, **instead of** fetching it from a URL via cURL? Or do you want the option to do either?

Comment: Yaa curl comment got deleted while adding codes here, have added them now. I wish to create a form which takes a url as input and save file to server. Something like http://example.com/example.jpg

Comment: For something as simple as that, I suggest you use [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of messing about with cURL. While cURL gives you more granular control over the request to get the file, that's not what you need here, and if you need to add some headers or (for some bizarre reason) POST to get the file, you can do that with a stream context.

Comment: file_get_contents() do not work on my shared server :(

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` disabled (`var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));`)? Seems odd they should allow cURL but not `allow_url_fopen`...

Comment: file_get_content works but it gives output as string in echo.

And my basic trouble is to get file info from url above

     $fileName = $_FILES['url']['name'];
     $fileSize = $_FILES['url']['size'];
     $fileType = $_FILES['url']['type'];
     $filePath = $dir . $fileName;

these work only when input type is file but not when text.

Comment: You have to write the file to disk or otherwise handle data to get that info, hang on i'm nearly done with an answer

Comment: thanx, am waiting. just bit more clarification url is external file and i wish to save it to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">URL:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" size=40 value="http://" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Why is this a <th> and not a <td> ? -->
      <th colspan="2"><input name="upload" type="submit" class="box" id="upload" value="Upload" /></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<?php

  set_time_limit(0);
  ini_set('display_errors',true);//Just in case we get some errors, let us know....

  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

    // Build local file system paths
    $baseDir = "./files";
    $fileName = basename(rtrim($_POST['url'],'/')); // This means that if someone specifies the root of a domain (/) it will call the local file "domain"
    $filePath = rtrim($baseDir,'/')."/$fileName";

    // Try to parse the URL we have been given and add any missing required info
    if ((!$parts = parse_url($_POST['url'])) || !isset($parts['host'])) die('ERROR: The specified URL is invalid');
    $url = (isset($parts['scheme']) && $parts['scheme']) ? $parts['scheme'].'://' : 'http://';
    if (isset($parts['user']) && $parts['user']) {
      $url .= $parts['user'];
      if (isset($parts['pass']) && $parts['pass']) $url .= ':'.$parts['pass'];
      $url .= '@';
    }
    $url .= $parts['host'];
    if (isset($parts['port']) && $parts['port']) $url .= ':'.$parts['port'];
    $url .= (isset($parts['path']) && $parts['path']) ? $parts['path'] : '/';
    if (isset($parts['query']) && $parts['query']) $url .= '?'.$parts['query'];
    if (isset($parts['fragment']) && $parts['fragment']) $url .= '#'.$parts['fragment'];

    print("Fetching file '$url' to '$filePath'<br />\n");

    // Open a local file point in write mode
    if (file_exists($filePath)) die("ERROR: The file '$filePath' already exists");
    $fp = fopen($filePath,'w') or die("ERROR: Could not open local file '$filePath' for writing!");

    // Let's go cURLing...
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_exec($ch);
    $fileSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    $fileType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    $transferTime = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);

    print("cURL operation complete (took $transferTime seconds)<br />\n");

    // Close cURL and the local file pointer, we're done with them both
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    // Check the $fileSize reported by cURL is the same as the file size on disk
    if ($fileSize != ($fs = filesize($filePath))) {
      print("WARNING: file size reported by cURL ($fileSize bytes) does not match size of file on disk ($fs bytes)<br />\nUsing size of file on disk for DB insert<br />\n");
      $fileSize = $fs;
    }

    include ('db.php');
    $query = "INSERT INTO upload2 (name, size, type, path ) ".
    "VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($fileName)."', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '".mysql_real_escape_string($filePath)."')";

    print("Running MySQL Query: $query<br />\n");

    mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close($conn);

    print('Done!');

  }

?>
```

Comment: Added a couple extra bits of spacing to make it more readable, and an extra comment

Comment: thanx a lot, gonna test it now

Comment: Keep in mind that it's just a basic framework - it doesn't, for example, account for people uploading two files with the same name, it just rejects the second request.

Comment: I understand, but it just dose what I need. Thanx again